# Registry value may equal to null

Tags: c#

How can I fix this issue where the VS tells me that it might output null value of `Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Control Panel\Desktop").GetValue("TranscodedImageCache")`?

```
byte[] path = (byte[])Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Control Panel\Desktop").GetValue("TranscodedImageCache");
String wallpaperFile = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(SliceMe(path, 24)).TrimEnd("\0".ToCharArray());
```

Comment: That means the call might return a null. Net 6 has nullable enabled by default. That's a good thing. Your should Google it and learn how to use it, because it's a very song feature. It prevents all kinds of common bugs of used correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using .NET 6, try the following:

```
using RegistryKey? subkey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Control Panel\Desktop");
byte[]? path = (byte[]?)subkey?.GetValue("TranscodedImageCache");

                    ...
```

---

**VS 2022**:

In a .NET 6 project, the `Nullable` setting can be found:

- In VS menu, click **Project**
- Select ***<project name>* Properties**
- Expand **Build**
- Setting name is: **Nullable**

The following can also be seen in the `.csproj` file: `<Nullable>enable</Nullable>`

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0-windows</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

---

**Resources**:

- [using statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement)
- [Nullable value types (C# reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/nullable-value-types)
- [Nullable reference types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references)
- [Default values of C# types (C# reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/default-values)

Here's some additional resources that may be of interest:

- [?? and ??= operators (C# reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator)
- [?: operator (C# reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator)

Comment: I think you can just write `byte[]? path = subkey?.GetValue("TranscodedImageCache");` not needing the if (or even var it)

Comment: What’s the question mark for?

Comment: I've added resources which explain the use of `?`.